# A way to send multiple parameter to async socket function?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, python-asyncio

After a lot of trials with httpio, requests, socket I'm seeing that no matter how I approach the solution it still behaves like a synchronous program even with an async function. the code is -

```
import socket
import time
import asyncio


t1 = time.time()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
target = '72.221.171.130'


#async socket to connect to the target with a given port

async def connect(port):
    try:
        s.connect((target, port))
        print(port)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([connect(port) for port in range(4100, 4150)]))

#printing time taken to scan ports two decimal places

print('Time taken to scan ports:', round((time.time() - t1),3), 'seconds')
```

I looking for the open port which is 4145. but this takes around 20 seconds to execute. I'm a beginner in async programming so I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do 50 things in parallel with ONE socket.  Have you tried creating a new socket inside the `connect` function?

Comment: Also, the call to `s.connect` performs I/O, that is a good place to `await` and get some improvement. In general you should use the methods provided by `asyncio` to handle connections, like `loop.sock_connect`, [asynchronous version of `socket.connect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.sock_connect).